# Is dateadd() slow in on-conditions compared to where-clauses?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a situation in a `select`, where it gets faster if I move `dateadd()` from the `on`-condition to the `where`-clause.

But sometimes it may not be possible to move it from the `on`-condition and to `where`-clause.  My solution was to move the `dateadd()` from the `on`-condition to a temporary table instead, and that sped up the entire stored procedure.

But I am left wondering; can it really be true that `dateadd()` is slower in an `on`-condition than elsewhere?

Comment: Can you show the query please? Hard to say otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer with some references for SQL Server unless I can find exact Sybase references but all Query Optimisers work similarly

To start, a DATEADD function on a predicate invalidates index usage (see [number 2 here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes)).

The ON clause is form of predicate of course (think of the old implicit-JOIN-in-WHERE syntax) so the same applies.

Now, queries honour a [logical processing step](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-executio) (if not actual, that's why "Query Optimisers" are called so). ON before WHERE is one of them.

With DATEADD in the WHERE clause, it is a residual filter because the main work has been done in the ON clause to restrict rows. If the DATEADD is in the ON clause, it gets processed "sooner" than the WHERE clause.

This is as per [Sybase JOIN docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1502/html/sqlug/sqlug169.htm) state

> ...the optimizer can only consider indexes on column names. Any type of operator or expression in combination with the column name means that the optimizer does not evaluate using an index on the column as a possible access method. If the columns in the join are of incompatible datatypes, the optimizer can consider an index on only one of the columns.

The query processing order is hinted at in this [Sybase doc](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1502/html/sqlug/sqlug169.htm)

The same thing applies to outer table filters in LEFT JOINS, really: in this case the WHERE clause is too late after the LEFT JOIN. Or why NOT EXISTS almost always beats LEFT JOIN .. IS NULL. See this for [Sybase OUTER JOINS](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1502/html/sqlug/sqlug169.htm)

DATEADD itself isn't the problem: it is the logical query processing order that makes it appear one